# Unable to match sendmail "Connection rate limit exceeded" with fail2ban

Tags: fail2ban

I can't manage to find the error preventing fail2ban to match these lines:

```
Apr 19 20:17:12 localhost sm-mta[201892]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=[12.345.7.789], arg2=12.345.7.789, relay=host.hostname.com [12.345.7.789] (may be forged), reject=421 4.3.2 Connection rate limit exceeded.
Apr 19 20:17:53 localhost sm-mta[201902]: 13JIHpTD201902: [12.345.7.789] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA-v4
```

Here is the associated fail2ban configuration:

```
[Definition]

_daemon = (?:(sm-(mta|acceptingconnections)|sendmail))
__prefix_line = %(known/__prefix_line)s(?:\w{14,20}: )?

prefregex = ^<F-MLFID>%(__prefix_line)s</F-MLFID><F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$

cmnfailre = ^ruleset=check_relay, arg1=(?P<dom>\S+), arg2=(?:IPv6:<IP6>|<IP4>), relay=((?P=dom) )?\[(\d+\.){3}\d+\](?: \(may be forged\))?, reject=421 4\.3\.2 (Connection rate limit exceeded\.|Too many open connections\.)$
            ^(?:\S+ )?\[(?:IPv6:<IP6>|<IP4>)\](?: \(may be forged\))? did not issue (?:[A-Z]{4}[/ ]?)+during connection to (?:TLS)?M(?:TA|S[PA])(?:-\w+)?$
```

I am testing with `fail2ban-regex test-mail.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sendmail-reject.conf`

Resulting in:

```
Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [5] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 5 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 5 missed
[processed in 0.00 sec]
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second message (`did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN`) can be found if you would set mode `aggressive` by `sendmail-reject` jail (after this [fix](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/07fa9f29129f53924f6850f01adeb8fb7c699060), e. g. v.0.10.6 and 0.11.2).

There was indeed no exact rule for the first message (`rate limit exceeded`) matching this kind of message exactly, due to different handling on the arguments, but...
I fixed this now in [f0214b3](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/f0214b3d36ea08b318c52a2d51fce50bf9ec0cce) on github.

Unless not released you can extend it by yourselves either in filter (copy & paste from [github filter](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.10/config/filter.d/sendmail-reject.conf)) or directly in jail:

```
[sendmail-reject]
enabled = true
mode = aggressive 
failregex = %(known/failregex)s
            ^ruleset=check_relay(?:, arg\d+=\S*)*, relay=(\S+ )?\[?<ADDR>\]?(?: \(may be forged\))?, reject=421 4\.3\.2 (Connection rate limit exceeded\.|Too many open connections\.)$"
            ^(?:\S+ )?\[<ADDR>\](?: \(may be forged\))? did not issue \S+ during connection
```

Comment: I've noticed you answer a lot of questions about fail2ban. Please note that fail2ban is off topic on SO. Hover over the tag. Please do not answer off topic questions. [answer] Vote to close them instead.

Comment: Although I understand the intention, but I appreciate the effort of people invested to write and format a question, and don't really see how a closing of question should be better than a simplest answering (also helping to "close" it). Let alone the closed as offtop answers don't disapear from SO etc, so arrives in search results on SO (and google and co), so would confuse people searching for the same questions. Moreover it is pity that stack exchange platform does not provide functionality to move a question from one site to another (better matching the topic).